# error comparing inputted value from input text and compare with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I have a database and it has columns `user_login, user_password`

I want to create a login page which has the callback function to compare the inputted `user_login` & `user_password` and compare it to the database.

I am using this code

```
@app.callback(
    Output('alert','children'),
    [Input('form-button-login','n_clicks')],
    [State('login-user-input','value'), State('login-pass-input','value')]
)
def auth(n, username, password):
    df = pd.read_sql(query,engine)
    input_pass = hash(password)
    if df.loc[(input_pass == df["user_password"]),"user_password"] == True:
        print('found')
    else:
        print('not found')
```

Seems I can not compare the ***inputted password*** and the specific value of the database. It result with this error instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1031, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 966, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "c:\Users\Kenny Putrajaya\Desktop\GAB\apps\login.py", line 48, in auth
    if df.loc[(input_pass != df["user_password"]),"user_password"] == True:
  File "D:\Software\Python 3.6.8\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

any solution?

Comment: `(input_pass == df["user_password"]).any()` Would work. Why comparing pass word again with boolean `True` !!!...print what it returns `df.loc[(input_pass == df["user_password"]),"user_password"]`

Comment: sorry my mistake, I am not aware that df.loc function would print a series object. Thank you! @DishinHGoyani

Comment: No problem. Now you know 